# Editing Control showing can not key any character in datagridviewcell on cell formatting

Tags: c#, cell-formatting

I'm develop an window form with a `datagridview`.

I wish to let user key in the date in the `datagridviewcell`.

First I'm using this code to format the cell

```
private void EditingControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            Control editingControl = (Control)sender;
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(editingControl.Text + e.KeyChar, pattern))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
     private string pattern = "^[0-9]{0,2}$";
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.EditingControl.KeyPress -= EditingControl_KeyPress;
        dataGridView1.EditingControl.KeyPress += EditingControl_KeyPress;
    }
```

But the cell only can let the user type in 3 integer.
So I using another pattern to format the cell

```
private void EditingControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            Control editingControl = (Control)sender;
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(editingControl.Text + e.KeyChar, pattern))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private string pattern = "^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$";

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.EditingControl.KeyPress -= EditingControl_KeyPress;
        dataGridView1.EditingControl.KeyPress += EditingControl_KeyPress;
    }
```

But I cannot type anything on the cell any more using this pattern.

How to format the cell that can let user type in the date formatted like this `yyyy-MM-dd`?